# What does this Awk expression mean

Tags: awk

I am working with bash script that has this command in it.

```
awk -F ‘‘ ‘/abc/{print $3}’|xargs
```

What is the meaning of this command?? Assume input is provided to awk.

Comment: the `-F` is a field separator whatever is the value after that and it looks like it is using unicode/smart quotes? `/abc/{print $3}` means if the line has `abc` in it print whatever is in field/column `3` and  pipe `|` the output to `xargs`

Comment: @TMSuhas :  Please copy and paste the command exactly as it is provided. In the way you wrote it, it is syntactically not valid (wrong quotes, missing space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is it'll do different things depending on the version of awk you're running and how many fields of output the awk script produces.

I assume you meant to write:

```
awk -F '' '/abc/{print $3}'|xargs
```

not the syntactically invalid (due to "smart quotes"):

```
awk -F ‘’’/abc/{print $3}’|xargs
```

`-F ''` is undefined behavior per POSIX so what it will do depends on the version of awk you're running. In some awks it'll split the current line into 1 character per field. in others it'll be ignored and the line will be split into fields at every sequence of white space. In other awks still it could do anything else.

`/abc/` looks for a string matching the regexp `abc` on the current line and if found invokes the subsequent action, in this case `{print $3}`.

However it's split into fields, `print $3` will print the 3rd such field.

`xargs` as used will just print chunks of the multi-line input it's getting all on 1 line so you could get 1 line of all-fields output if you don't have many fields being output or several lines of multi-field output if you do.

I suspect the intent of that code was to do what this code actually will do in any awk alone:

```
awk '/abc/{printf "%s%s", sep, substr($0,3,1); sep=OFS} END{print ""}'
```

e.g.:

```
$ printf 'foo\nxabc\nyzabc\nbar\n' |
    awk '/abc/{printf "%s%s", sep, substr($0,3,1); sep=OFS} END{print ""}'
b a
```